# SQLAlchemy build filter condition based on user inputs

Tags: sqlalchemy

In `sqlalchemy`, how to build filter condition based on user selections? This is what I tried, but doesn't seem to work

```
  conditions =[]
  if input.userid: 
    conditions.append( userdata.uid == input.userid)
  if input.location:
    conditions.append( userdata.location.like(f"{input.location}%") )
  if input.username: 
    conditions.append( userdata.username.like(f"%{input.username}%")  )
```

So based on user inputs, there may be 1, 2 or 3 filter conditions in the `and_` operator. Below is my query

```
records = session.query(userdata).filter(and_(conditions)).all()
```

Or is it better to use `from sqlalchemy.sql import text` and generate a normal SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do it like this-

```
query = session.query(userdata)
if input.userid:
  query = query.filter(userdata.uid==input.userid)
if input.location:
  query = query.filter(userdata.location.like(f"{input.location}%"))

records = query.all()
```

Comment: Becottle : Works great !. So it keeps appending to existing query.

Comment: The pattern is "generative" - so ".filter()" returns a modified version of the original query. Lets you chain a whole bunch of .filter and the like together to build the final query.